How well can $e$ be approximated?
It is well known that the constant $e=2.718...$ is an irrational number. As such it has an infinite sequence of fractions $\frac pq$ that approximate it reasonably well, namely better than the error term $q^{-2}$ (see Dirichlet's approximation theorem). That is the set $R\subset \mathbb Q$ of all numbers $\frac pq$ that satisfy the following inequality is infinite: \begin{align*}0<\left|e-\frac pq\right|<q^{-2}\end{align*} But how well can we improve that upper bound? Which functions $f(q)$ can we use, such that the error remains below $1/f(q)$? It is known that the irrationality measure of $e$ is exactly two. This implies that any function $q^{2+\varepsilon}$ for $\varepsilon>0$ is impossible. However we do know that any $f(q)=Aq^2$ for $A\in\mathbb R^+$ does work! (See Markov constant of $e$.) So which functions with growth rates in between $Aq^2$ and $q^{2+\varepsilon}$ work? What about $q^2\ln q$? What is the best (we know) we can do?

It turns out that we've basically solved this problem completely, because $e$ has a known continued fraction. The $q^{-2}$ can be replaced by
$$
\frac{(\tfrac12+\varepsilon)\log\log q}{q^2\log q}
$$
for any $\varepsilon>0$ but not for any $\varepsilon<0$. See this 1978 paper of Davis for example.

Are there similar results for other numbers? For example what about the cube root of 2?

Other than quadratic irrational numbers, there are very few numbers where we can find the complete continued fraction, which is required for this sort of strong result. In particular, we know very little about the long-term continued fraction for $\sqrt[3]2$, and I don't think anything stronger than Roth's theorem is known.
